# Nutch 2.x plugin issue

Tags: java, eclipse, web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to call the whole crawling pipeline in Nutch 2.x and it is working using the bin/crawl command line. However, I believe it is not running the the parse-html plugin defined in the nutch-sites.xml. I found on the wiki that you can call a plugin using the bin/nutch etc... however, I am wondering how to call a plugin on ECLIPSE when running all the jobs from the injectors till the indexing.
Hence, my question is how to run a plugin in Nutch 2.x on Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.